# Powershell PSSlack Module send-slackapi invite.admin.users

Tags: powershell, module, slack-api

I'm using Powershell module "PSSlack" to send api call, using the method users.admin.invite.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSSlack/0.0.17/Content/Public%5CSend-SlackAPI.ps1

This is what I wrote:

```
$token = xoxp-XXXX
$email = "someone@domain.com"
Send-SlackApi -Token $token -Method users.admin.invite -Proxy $email -Verbose`
```

This is the error I get:

```
Send-SlackApi : Slack API call failed: This operation is not supported for a relative URI.
At line:6 char:1
+ Send-SlackApi -Token $token -Method users.admin.invite -Proxy $email  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Send-SlackApi
VERBOSE: Something went wrong.  $Response is $null
```

Answer (score 1):

ok I found out that this is the correct syntax:

```
$token = xoxp-XXXX
$email = "someone@domain.com"
Send-SlackApi -Token $token -Method users.admin.invite?email=$email
```